# C# delegate consequence: don't like the public method

Tags: c#, delegates

I'm learning C#. Now I'm fiddling with delegates and events. My question is regarding the delegate: it seems I *must* keep the method **public virtual bool IsPromotable(Employee e, PromotionDelegate pd)** public. Suppose I want it protected. What do I do now? Or is this example a bad use of the delegate? Or must I simply accept public methods when using delegates? Below is the fully compilable code:

```
using System;

namespace Delegate_Tutorial_1
{

    public class EmployeeEventArgs : EventArgs
    {
        public Employee Employee { get; set; }
    }

    //--

    public class Employee
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int YearsOfService { get; set; }

        public event EventHandler<EmployeeEventArgs> HourlyRateChanged;

        private double hourlyRate;
        public double HourlyRate
        {
            get { return hourlyRate; }
            set
            {
                if (hourlyRate != value)
                {
                    hourlyRate = value;
                    OnHourlyRateChanged();
                }
            }
        }

        protected virtual void OnHourlyRateChanged()
        {
            if (HourlyRateChanged != null)
                HourlyRateChanged(this, new EmployeeEventArgs() { Employee = this});
        }


        public virtual bool IsPromotable(Employee e, PromotionDelegate pd)
        {
            return pd(e);
        }
    }
}

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Delegate_Tutorial_1
{
    public delegate bool PromotionDelegate(Employee emp);

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            PromotionDelegate promoDelegate = PromotionCheck;

            List<Employee> EmployeeList = new List<Employee>();
            EmployeeList.Add(new Employee() { Name = "John", YearsOfService = 5, HourlyRate = 15 });
            EmployeeList.Add(new Employee() { Name = "Mary", YearsOfService = 4, HourlyRate = 17 });

            foreach (Employee emp in EmployeeList)
            {
                emp.HourlyRateChanged += OnHourlyRateChanged; //Subscribe to the event of the Employee

                if (emp.IsPromotable(emp, promoDelegate))
                {
                    emp.HourlyRate *= 1.1;
                    Console.WriteLine(emp.Name + " : eligable for promotion. Salary now is: " + emp.HourlyRate);
                }
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }


        //--

        public static bool PromotionCheck(Employee emp)
        {
            return emp.YearsOfService >= 5 ? true : false;
        }

        public static void OnHourlyRateChanged(object source, EmployeeEventArgs args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hourly salary has been changed for: " + args.Employee.Name);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand this question. The accessibility of a method (e.g. `public`, `protected`, etc.) has nothing to do with whether a method can be used to initialize a delegate type instance. When overriding a method, you do have to match the base class's method declaration, including accessibility, but that doesn't really have anything to do with delegates per se (even though the concepts are similar in effect).

Comment: Please provide [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reproduces whatever error you're actually getting, and provide a clear, precise description of what that code does and how that's different from what you want.

Comment: I have thought a little longer before I decided to respond to you. You're right, if that's important. You're right, my question is vague indeed and I recognize the difference in styles between you and Enigmativity. Both of you have been helpful in your respective ways. The reason for the vagueness is because I'm not comfortable with the architecture of this particular code. Yes, it's a learning process, but I don't mind thinking ahead. The vagueness is a direct consequence of me not being a grand architect myself to define the problem domain correctly. I hope this response is satisfying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fact that you need to call `IsPromotable` on your `Employee` class from your class `Program` is the reason that it needs to be `public`. It has nothing to do with whether or not you're using delegates.

Being `public` it has all of the virtues of being `protected` anyway. All of the `Employee` class descendants can see `IsPromotable` and override it (as it is also `virtual`).

Now, just a couple of other hints for you.

With your `OnHourlyRateChanged` method in `Employee` you should structure the code like this:

```
protected virtual void OnHourlyRateChanged()
{
    var hrc = this.HourlyRateChanged;
    if (hrc != null)
    {
        hrc(this, new EmployeeEventArgs() { Employee = this });
    }
}
```

The reason is that in multi-threaded code the delegate may change from after the check but before the call. It doesn't happen often, but when it does it can cause your program to throw an exception and it becomes very hard to debug. Your code may not be multi-threaded, but you should always get into using this pattern as a habit.

Also, in `Program` you have called the event handler `OnHourlyRateChanged`. The normal convention is to use the `On*` naming for the method that raises the event, but not for the method that handles the event. It is more common for this method to be called something like `Employee_HourlyRateChanged`. Again this is a good habit to get into to avoid ambiguity in the future.

Comment: The above looks like a good guess as to what the OP is actually asking. Let's hope they come back and explain themselves, so we can tell for sure.

Comment: @PeterDuniho - Thanks. I thought the question was fairly clear. What do you think they might be asking instead?

Comment: Maybe I'm just too literal-minded, but I generally try to avoid speculating at all with a question that is so unclear. I respect that others approach answering differently, and you may well have guessed correctly. Certainly, it's a better guess than I'd be able to make.

Comment: Ah, thanks on the advices. But now to the original question: suppose I want said public method (IsPromotable) to be protected? How do I solve the problem of delegating the details elsewhere? Or is this simply not a problem at all? Or maybe I should have used some other design pattern to delegate the details of IsPromotable. The point is to keep the Employee class re-usable so others can define what a promotion actually is.

Comment: @PeterDuniho - I'm afraid you're right. The question wasn't clear at all.,

Comment: @Valmont - The way your code is now it is probably fine, but in this kind of class you would typically see a pair of methods - `IsPromotable` and `Promote` - and the latter would throw an exception if the former doesn't evaluate to `true`. In this case to delegate two methods you would usually create a class, say `PromotionPolicy`, that encapsulates both methods and you would pass that to each `Employee` either thru its constructor or via each method.

Comment: @Enigmativity - I needed to consume this as I'm a beginner. But I did iencapsulate it in a PromotionPolicy class and totally see the benefit. I don't feel welcomed in my first post here but I have learned a lot already.